# Enabling screen sharing in Wayland on Rocky 8 in Gnome

Tags: gnome, wayland, xdg

I'm trying to get screen sharing to work on a machine running Rocky 8.8 and using Gnome as its desktop environment using Wayland.  The screen sharing tool I'm using is screego, which runs in a web browser.  I have current versions of firefox (version 102) and gnome (version 110) installed.

I'm trying to follow the instructions found here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Desktop_Portal

It states I need to install the xdg-desktop-portal package and the corresponding xdg-desktop-portal-gnome backend.  However, I can't seem to find an available xdg-desktop-portal-gnome RPM package to install.  It doesn't appear to be available in the standard Rocky repositories.

I've been able to find xdg-desktop-portal-kde (included in epel) and kdg-desktop-portal-gtk (included in rocky appstream) packages.  But I'm using Gnome, so I'm sure I need xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.

I've found the github repository for xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.  Do I need to build from source at this point in time?